# Iterate MySQL records and create a JSON in GoLang

Tags: mysql, json, go

I'm trying to read data from a MySQL database from my Go app.

```
var queryStr string = "SELECT * FROM Customers"
rows, err := db.Query(queryStr)

defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    // do stuffs
}
```

The query it's ok and it works; now I'd like to easily map each record of the MySQL query to a Customer object that I've previuosly defined as showed below:

```
type Customer struct {
    id              IntegerType     `json:"id"`
    name            string          `json:"name"`
    surname         string          `json:"surname"`
}
```

How can I do that?

Second question: once I get an array of Customer object how can I easily put it into a new JSON object under a specific key called "data"?

thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) fields so they can be used on JSON:

```
type Customer struct {
   ID      int         `json:"id"`
   Name    string      `json:"name"`
   Surname string      `json:"surname"`
}
```

Declare a value to be marshaled to JSON:

```
var v struct {
    Data []Customer `json:"data"`
}
```

Query for the specific fields:

```
var queryStr string = "SELECT id, name, surname FROM Customers"
rows, err := db.Query(queryStr)
```

Loop through rows adding to value.

```
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
    // Scan one customer record
    var c Customer
    if err := rows.Scan(&c.ID, &c.Name, &c.Surnmae); err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    v.Data = append(v.Data, c)
}
if rows.Err() != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Marshal the value to JSON

```
p, err := json.Marshal(v)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

The value `p` is a []byte containing the JSON.

Comment: High quality answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I didn't understand some things: 1) when you define the var v struct, what name I have to assign to the Customer array inside the struct? I've written "Data" but I got an "unresolved reference 'Data'. :(
2) when I write if rows.Err() != nil it says: Unresolved type 'nil', how can I fix this? Have I to import something more? 3) I've defined a variable as:  var p[] byte, then I've written p, errorsMarsh := json.Marshal(v) but it says "unused variable p" but it is not true, am I missing something? thanks in advance

Comment: 1) I fixed typo re: data.  2) nil is a [predeclared identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Predeclared_identifiers). No need to import anything to use it. 3) my example code uses a short variable declaration, you don't need to declare `p`.